# LISP Exercice Fam Tr

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

[image: Family Tree Exercise]

I'm trying to do this exercise like this:

```
(defconstant *family-tree* 
  '((father Barack Pat) (mother Michelle Pat)
    (father GeorgeW Peter) (mother Laura Peter)
    (father GeogerH James (mother Barbara James) 
    (father Bill Jane) (mother Hillary Jane) 
    (father James Mark) (mother Jane Mark) 
    (father Peter Mary) (mother Pat Mary) 
    (father Mark John) (mother Mary John))))
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best way. Moreover, I have no idea how to create the function "parents" and "grandparents". I really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to start with baby steps:

```
(defun make-person (name &optional father mother)
  (cons name (cons father mother)))
```

Now you can create your family tree:

```
(defconstant *family-tree* 
  (make-person 'john
     (make-person 'mark 
       (make-person 'james
         ...)
       (make-person 'jane
         ...))
     (make-person 'mary
       (make-person ...)
       (make-person ...))))
```

Finding a person in the tree requires recursion:

```
(defun find-person (tree name)
  (if (eq (car tree) name)
      tree
      (or (find-person (cadr tree) name)
          (find-person (cddr tree) name))))
```

where you can actually replace `cadr` with `father-tree` and `cddr` with `mother-tree`.
(you can also define `tree-name` to call `car`).

Finding parents and grandparents should now be easy:

```
(defun parents (tree name)
   (let ((person (find-person tree name)))
     (list (caadr person) ; or (tree-name (tree-father person))
           (caddr person)))) ; or ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You've constructed a list of associative records, which is a valid way of approaching this problem. This similar to the structure of a database table that is not indexed. You could have used a tree structure as well with a backtracking search, however this is more complex to implement and for a small set of results, the efficiency gains will not be much.

Also given that the problem doesn't require you to look up mothers and fathers separately, but just parents, it'd probably be more efficient to put both parents in the record like such

```
(defconstant *family-tree*
  '((john mark mary)
    (mark james jane)
    (james georgeh barbara)
    ; and so on ...
   ))
```

Given this structure let's write some accessor functions

```
(defun child (record)
  "This function returns the child in a family tree record. 
    For example (child '(john mark mary)) returns JOHN"
    (car record))

(defun parents (record)
  "This function returns the parents in a family record.
   For example (cdr '(john mark mary)) returns (MARK MARY)"
   (cdr record))

(defun find-record (family-tree person)
  "This function returns the record of which PERSON is the CHILD.
   For example (find-record 'john '((mark james jane) (john mark mary))) 
   returns (JOHN MARK MARY)"
  (find-if (lambda (record) (eql (child record) person)) family-tree))
```

Now using these accessors we can write the parent function

```
(defun parents (family-tree person)
  (parents (find-record family-tree person)))
```

Now to find the grandparents you need to find the parents for each parent.

```
(defun grandparents (family-tree person)
    (apply #'append
           (mapcar (lambda (parent) (parents family-tree parent)
                   (parents family-tree person))))
```

Now that last function is a little complex, so let's explain it. In order to find the grandparents, you need to first find the parents of the person you're looking for, that's the bottom-most line `(parents family-tree person)`. That will result in a list of parents, so for each parent in that list, we need to find their parents (parent of a parent == grandparent), so we use `mapcar` to call `(parent family-tree parent)` on each result. Finally we're going to have a list of 2 lists as a result, so we need to `append` them into a single list.

Comment: I really appreciate your attention.
It was what I'm looking for.
Thank you so much for your explanation and comments, it was really helpful.
Looking at it now I understood how it works.

Thanks again,
best regards

Comment: No problem. Keep lisping! I haven't evaluated any of that code since I don't have my Lisp environment on hand, so do be aware of any typos or bugs, but the gist of the solution is there. Also, if you want to be really showy you could use ``(find person family-tree :key #'child)`` as the implementation of ``FIND-RECORD``.